# Find Fourier Transform of the even function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, spherical-harmonics

Let $S^n$ be an $n$-dimentional unit sphere.

Consider $f: S^n \longrightarrow R_+$ even continuous function.

Denote
$$
F(f):=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{S^n}f(y)g\left(\frac{|xy|}{t}\right)dy\frac{dt}{t^{n+1}},
$$
where $x \in S^n, \, t>0$ and function $g$ is such that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}s^jg(s)ds=0, \quad j=0,2,4,\ldots, 2\left[(n-1)/2\right]
$$
$$
\int_1^{\infty}s^{\alpha}|g(s)|ds< \infty, \quad \alpha>n-1.
$$

Find Fourier Transform of $F$.